# Databinding within ComboBox: Use Usercontrol to display each item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I have a model-class Person and a UserControl PersonComboBoxItem to display it.

What I'd like to do, is, creating a `ComboBox` where its ItemsSource is bound to my `ObservableCollection<Person>` called People and use my PersonUserControl to display each Person within the collection.

```xml
<Grid>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" >            
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:PersonComboBoxItem Person="{Binding ###how do I get the current item here to set the property 'Person' on my PersonComboBoxItem class? ###  }"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

I already worked my way thorugh this [great article about databinding on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx), but I couldn't get the transition over to my design-approach. 
Feel free to critisize it - I'm not sure, if this is the WPF-way to do it.

Regards, Florian

P.S.: My sample code can be downloaded from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1429970/ComboboxWithItemUserControl.zip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` in the `ItemTemplate` is the current `Person`, to bind directly to the `DataContext` and thus to the `Person` just use `{Binding}`.

You could design your `UserControl` to directly use the current `DataContext` instead of a `Person` property, then you do not need to set anything explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use an implicit `DataTemplate` to tell WPF how to draw the `Person` object when it encounters it in the visual tree

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">            
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                <local:PersonComboBoxItem />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

The `ComboBox` is already placing your `Person` data object in the `VisualTree`, and probably looks something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Person />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Person />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Person />
    </ContentPresenter>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

So you are simply replacing where it says  `<Person />` with a `<local:PersonComboBoxItem  />`. The `DataContext` of your `UserControl` will be set to your `Person` object as well

Also, the `DataContext` of the `PersonItemComboBox` will always be of type `Person`, so you won't even need the `Person` dependency property.

Comment: Thanks as well. I figured out, that I can only accept one answer as my 'accepted answer'. --> First come, first serve. ;-)